# How does the main function of the argparse template that ships with eclipse work in the interactive python shell?

Tags: python, program-entry-point

If you create a new python module in eclipse, you have the option to use a argparse template for your new module. Below are code fragments from this template.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
# encoding: utf-8
'''
eclipse_argparse -- shortdesc

eclipse_argparse is a description

It defines classes_and_methods

@author:     user_name

@copyright:  2015 organization_name. All rights reserved.

@license:    license

@contact:    user_email
@deffield    updated: Updated
'''
def main(argv=None): # IGNORE:C0111
    '''Command line options.'''

    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv
    else:
        sys.argv.extend(argv)

...

    program_shortdesc = __import__('__main__').__doc__.split("\n")[1]

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

'...' means that I omitted the parts of the code that seem not important to my question.
I saved the file under eclipse_argparse.py.
As far as I understand, the `main` function is given the argument `argv` so that one can call the main function interactively from the python shell and give it a parameter:

```
>>> import eclipse_argparse
>>> eclipse_argparse.main('-bla')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "eclipse_argparse.py", line 57, in main
    program_shortdesc = __import__('__main__').__doc__.split("\n")[1]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

But this is not possible because `__import__('__main__')` evaluates to `__main__`, and not to `eclipse_argparse` as I would expect.

`program_shortdesc` should then evaluated to `eclipse_argparse -- shortdesc`

Why does this happen? Is my assumption, that you should be able to call the main method with an argument in an interactive session wrong?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `argparse.py`, or `sys.argv`.  It's all about accessing the `__doc__` attribute of a module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a module, its own doc is available as `__doc__`.  You don't need to import anything, or reference `__main__` (which in the interactive shell points to shell environment, not any imported module).

This works when `main` is called from `if __name__` and from a shell:

```
def main(argv=None): # IGNORE:C0111
    # ...
    print __doc__
```

In a shell I can do:

```
>>> import stack27864002
>>> stack27864002.__doc__
'\neclipse_argparse -- ...'
>>> stack27864002.main()
# same
```

I wonder why this is called a `argparse template`, since it has nothing to do with `argparse.py` module.

The default value for `__doc__` is None, so it is a good idea to be prepared for that case - i.e. don't try to split it without first checking.

Answer (score 0):

To make the code work in an interactive shell session, the code

```
program_shortdesc = __import__('__main__').__doc__.split("\n")[1]
```

should be changed to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        program_shortdesc = __import__('__main__').__doc__.split("\n")[1]
    else:
        program_shortdesc = __doc__.split("\n")[1]
```

What confused me was that they provide a main method with the possibility to supply an argument (which implies that you could import the module in a python shell and call the main function with some parameter, like `import eclipse_argparse; eclipse_argparse.main('-some_parameter')`) and then define a variable `program_shortdesc` that only works when you call the program through the '__main__' 'entry point', like `python eclipse_argparse.py`